# ansible | how to call my vars inside a role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Below is my flowchart--

```
my-code
      plays
           play1
           play2
      roles
           role1
               vars1
               files1
               tasks1
               templates1
           role2
               vars2
               files2
               tasks2
               templates2
           role3
               vars3
               files3
               tasks3
               templates3
```

I want to create a single 'vars/defaults' folder for all of my variables for different roles to access. When I created a folder 'defaults/main.yml' , I am getting below error.

Error:-

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable
```

My requirement should be something like this-

```
my-code
          plays
               play1
               play2
          roles
               vars
                   main.yml
               role1
                   files1
                   tasks1
                   templates1
               role2
                   files2
                   tasks2
                   templates2
               role3
                   files3
                   tasks3
                   templates3
```

tasks/code.yml

```
- name: CODE | Downloading Presto and Kinesis Jars from S3
  shell: "aws s3 cp s3://services-{{ aws_accountid_test }}-cicd-storage/jars/ utilities/ --recursive"
  ignore_errors: yes
  args:
      chdir: /home/hadoop/code/
      executable: /bin/bash
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: hadoop
```

Comment: Maybe vars_file is what you are looking for.

Comment: @gile- You mean to say, I need to change the name of 'vars' to 'vars_file'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood your need, you can define your variables in e.g. `./vars.yml`

```
---

- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars_files:
    - ./vars.yml
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
```

Be careful to [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method that does not require you to explicitly include a vars file would be to modify your dir structure

```
my-code
      play1
      play2
      group_vars
          all.yml
      roles
           role1
               files1
               tasks1
               templates1
           role2
               files2
               tasks2
               templates2
           role3
               files3
               tasks3
               templates3
```

All the common vars you want available to all hosts are then placed in 'all.yml' and included automatically. You can then further target variables by adding '_group_name_.yml' into the 'group_vars' directory, to set variables only exposed to hosts in those particular groups.

For more info on best practice for directory/file layout, check out [this section of the docs.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html)

Comment: @clockworknet- I have created similar structure but I am getting the same error mentioned in my question. Updated my question with my task/code.yml

Comment: Note that in my answer, the plays have been moved into the root directory, and are no longer in a 'plays' directory. Is that what you have tried? This is important as Ansible looks for the 'group_vars' directory in the same directory as your play files. As per the linked docs, they should be located in the same directory that contains your roles directory.

Comment: I cannot change my workflow. I need to add the vars as per my requirement and cannot go with your suggestion. Could you suggest anything within my workflow..?

Comment: Try moving the 'group_vars' directory inside the plays directory.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: Not sure what to suggest - the suggestion in my answer is how a large codebase I look after works. The group_vars directory can either be placed in the directory containing the plays or the directory containing the inventory. You have already moved away from Ansibles recommendations and in doing so, I guess that you need a custom ansible.cfg to make the roles work. Can you update your answer to include the contents of your ansible.cfg, the contents of your all.yml and how you are calling the playbooks?